# Micronaut controller responds with error when the validation fails

Tags: java, microservices, micronaut

I am trying to write a Micronaut service which returns a specific response when data has validation errors.

```java
  @Post(value = "/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response<Category> save(@Valid @Body Category category) {
    Category savedCategory = categoryService.save(category);
    Response<Category> response = new Response<>("Category Saved Successfully", State.SUCCESS,
        savedCategory);
    return response;
  }

  @Error(exception = ConstraintViolationException.class)
  public Response<Category> onSavedFailed(HttpRequest request, ConstraintViolationException ex) {
    Optional<Category> requestBody = request.getBody(Category.class);
    Response<Category> response = new Response<>("", State.FAILED, requestBody.get());
    response.addErrors(messageSource.violationsMessages(ex.getConstraintViolations()));
    System.out.println(response); // [1] THIS LINE IS EXECUTED
    return response;
  }
```

This code seems to be working correctly because when I call the code using the following test the line marked [1] is executed properly.
But the in the test after catching the HttpClientResponseException I am not able to get the response object which was returned by the controller, what am I doing wrong?

```
@Test
  public void should_not_save_category_without_name(){
    try (RxHttpClient client = embeddedServer.getApplicationContext()
        .createBean(RxHttpClient.class, embeddedServer.getURL())) {
      Category category =  new Category("");
      Response<Category> retrieve = client.toBlocking()
          .retrieve(HttpRequest.POST("/categories", category),
              Argument.of(Response.class, Category.class));
    }catch (HttpClientResponseException exception){
      System.out.println(exception.getResponse().getStatus());
      System.out.println(exception);
    }
  }
```

This is what is printed in the test case

```
INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException: Internal Server Error
```

Here are the micronaut client logs

```
10:11:51.571 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Sending HTTP Request: POST /categories
10:11:51.572 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Chosen Server: localhost(6140)
10:11:51.574 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - host: localhost:6140
10:11:51.574 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - connection: close
10:11:51.574 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - content-type: application/json
10:11:51.574 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - content-length: 2
10:11:51.574 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Request Body
10:11:51.574 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - ----
10:11:51.574 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - {}
10:11:51.574 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - ----
Response{message='', errors=[name must not be blank], state=FAILED, data=Category{id=null, name=null}}
10:11:51.831 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - HTTP Client Response Received for Request: POST http://localhost:6140/categories
10:11:51.831 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
10:11:51.831 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Date: Wed, 8 Jan 2020 04:41:51 GMT
10:11:51.831 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - content-type: application/json
10:11:51.831 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - content-length: 64
10:11:51.831 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - connection: close
10:11:51.832 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Response Body
10:11:51.832 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - ----
10:11:51.832 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - {"errors":["name must not be blank"],"state":"FAILED","data":{}}
10:11:51.832 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - ----
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the error body you need to use the 3 parameters method in which the 3rd one is the error type: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/client/DefaultHttpClient.html#exchange-io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest-io.micronaut.core.type.Argument-io.micronaut.core.type.Argument-

So, your code should be something like:

```java
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.POST("/categories", category);
client.toBlocking().exchange(request, Argument.of(Object.class), Argument.of(JsonError));

...

exception.getResponse().getBody(Argument.of(Response.class, Category.class)) // This return an Optional
```

Also, to be make sure that everything works as expected and you're actually getting the error you can enable the trace for the `HttpClient` adding the following to `logback.xml`:

```xml
<configuration>
    ...
    ...

    <logger name="io.micronaut.http.client" level="TRACE" />

</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks a lot for your response. This almost worked, now if I print the exception then i see the response object. but when i do `exception.getResponse().getBody(Response.class)` I get `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
`

Comment: Without code to be able to run it's complicated to help. Have you tried using `exchange` instead of `retrieve` method? Have you enabled the log to see that the actual error response is being sent back?

Comment: I added the logs in the question, the code is also available at https://github.com/sapanparikh18/create-pub.The behavior was the same with the exchange method as well.

Comment: It worked as soon as I changed the getbody arguments as following exception.getResponse().getBody(Argument.of(Response.class, Category.class))